# Is it possible to pass a JS callback through JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I realise I can not pass a function object via JSON, is there another way to pass a callback function via JSON?

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    var state = e.state;

    switch(state['method']) {
        case 'updateFields':
            updateFields(state);
        break;
    }
}
```

Where `state` is structured something like this:

```
{'method':'updateFields', ...}
```

And I wish to remove the switch case and instead directly call the function, similar to this:

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    var state = e.state;

    state['method'](state);
}
```

I do not know how to make it work though.

Comment: It could be clearer and easier to answer if you post the code!

Comment: @3Dos Went ahead and reworded/added code examples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track; the main thing you need to change is to make all of your methods part of an object. Then you can use the method name to access the method directly from that object:

```
var methods = {
    updateFields: function( state ) {
        // do something with state
    },
    anotherMethod: function( state ) {
        // etc.
    }
};

window.onpopstate = function( e ) {
    var state = e.state;
    var method = methods[state.method];
    if( method ) {
        method( state );
    } else {
        console.log( "Unknown method", state.method );
    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of `if (method)` you could use `if (typeof method === 'function')` to be certain you can actually call it.

Comment: Good point! Given that this is used in a `popstate` listener, I was assuming that the JSON object in question is one that OP's own `pushState` or `replaceState` code created. But in a more general case, the `typeof` approach would be more bulletproof, so thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I like that approach more then the switch case, though I dislike that I still have to define the methods within `methods`. 

I was hoping for an approach where functions did not need to be listed and so could essentially be anonymous to the `'popstate'`event. While the `'popstate'` event in your code doesn't know what the functions are, they still need to be centrally stored within he `methods` object. 

If that makes sense, plus one still for much cleaner code then using switch cases (which I mostly despise).

Comment: You pretty much need to have the methods be members of some object or another; that's how you do this kind of name lookup in JavaScript. They don't necessarily have to be defined _inside the object literal_, though. You could do `var methods = {};` and then elsewhere do `methods.updateFields = function( state ) { ... };` if you prefer.

Comment: @MichaelGeary perfect that is a lot nicer and allows me to have a centralised `'popstate'` listener, and define the functions in other js files as needed :)